# How can we store page data into our custom table in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have HTML Page with two text fields called first & last name, I have created table using wordpress codex with my plugin. Now, when I click submit in HTML form page, I need to store the data which I enter in text fields into my own Table. Kindly give a simple example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following example creates a custom database table and inserts a row into the database. You can modify the INSERT query by replacing the variables with the values extracted from form fields. You can either store the INSERT SQL query in a string and use $wpdb -> query() function or directly use the $wpdb->insert() function to insert values into the table.

> function initialize_custom_table(){
>
> ```
>   global $wpdb;
>   $table_name = "customtable";
>   $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . $table_name . "` (
>                             `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>                             `name` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
>                             `value` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
>                             PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
>                             );" ;
>
>   $wpdb->query($sql);
>
>   $name = "Hello";
>   $value = "World";
>
>   $rows_affected = $wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
>                    'name' => $name, 'value' => $value));
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Thanks Nallu, and here static values are given, need to pass from HTML page, so can we use dynamic values here?

Comment: Yes. You can replace the static variables with form variables, for eg., use $_POST['name'] and $_POST['value'] if the name of the form fields are 'name' and 'value'

Comment: Plugin has one form with two text fields first and last name,when i activate that plugin, For example Form will display in index page, I need to store two fields data in Wordpress custom table at the same time ,need to pass those data's to next page. How can we have form action here ?

Comment: Dinesh, this question should be posted as a new question